# Unable to Sign-out using Devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2 app with Devise for authenticating users.

On local development mode, the Sign-out link is not working. It redirects me to home page instead of showing Sign-in page and the session is not destroyed. But on Heroku, clicking on Sign-out link properly logs me out and shows me the Sign-in page destroying the user session.

In application .haml layout page, the link to Sign-out page is:

```
= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Related routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }

      new_user_session  GET       /users/sign_in(.:format)       sessions#new
          user_session  POST      /users/sign_in(.:format)       sessions#create
  destroy_user_session  DELETE    /users/sign_out(.:format)      sessions#destroy
```

I have inherited the `Devise::SessionsController` to `SessionsController` in my app as below:

```
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    layout 'devise_layout'
  end
```

Now the weird case is that, after the session is expired which is default 30 minutes, I log in again and click on Sign-out link, it redirects me back to Sign-in page.

All works fine on Heroku, it fails on local. I am unable to figure it out what is happening on local.

I don't think I am doing anything wrong here because same is deployed to Heroku and is working fine there. What's wrong with development mode on local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops...answering late.

Anyway, I was able to figure out the issue. Actually the app is subdomain based. So I used `lvh.me:3000` for testing on local as `localhost:3000` doesnt support subdomain.

The workaround is to set subdomain as `"lvh.me" in session_store.rb.`

```
domain: 'lvh.me'
```